# Could not compute caller for function: public constructor Error when enable proguard in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, security, proguard, data-class

The project working well without enabling proguard, the problem comes when enable it, I am using retrofit with Moshi converter and Coroutines to fetch list of data, and Hilt for DI, and I added all rules and kept all models

This is the error:

> Could not compute caller for function: public constructor MovieListEntity(movie_data: kotlin.collections.List<com.***.***.domain.entities.MovieData>) defined in com.***.***.domain.entities.MovieListEntity[c@dad1eb0] (member = null)

And these are the classes mentioned

```
data class MovieListEntity(
     @field:Json(name = "movie_data")
     val movie_data: List<MovieData>
)
data class MovieData(
    @field:Json(name = "movie_id")
    val movie_id: Int,
    @field:Json(name = "sub_title")
    val sub_title: String,
    @field:Json(name = "title")
    val title: String
)
```

*Note: I tried also without annotations, and it didn't help*

These are the proguard rules:

```
-keep class com.***.***.domain.entitie.** { *; }
-keep class com.***.***.domain.entities.*
-keep class com.***.***.domain.entities.MovieListEntity
-keep class com.***.***.domain.entities.MovieData

-keep class com.***.***.DataBinderMapperImpl { *; }
-keep class com.***.***.DataBinderMapperImpl { *; }
-keep  class com.***.*****{
    public ** component1();
  <fields>;
 }
```

Plus other rules for retrofit, OkHttp, hilt .. etc.

**How Can I solve this error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** by adding these rules

```
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @com.squareup.moshi.FromJson <methods>;
    @com.squareup.moshi.ToJson <methods>;
}

-keepnames @kotlin.Metadata class com.******.domain.entities.**
-keep class com.******.domain.entities.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.*****.domain.entities.** { *; }
```

The problem was in **Moshi library**, [check this](https://github.com/square/moshi/issues/345#issuecomment-337328427)